# Monitoring HTTP / SNMP / email requests?

Tags: .net, http, email, monitoring, snmp

I need a .NET application that will run as a service / background and emit out sounds when any of these events is detectced:
- E-mail is sent
- SNMP packet is sent
- or HTTP Post request is made
Any help would be much appreciated!

At least on how to monitor one of them would be great!

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can [extend Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/Fiddler/dev/IFiddlerExtension.asp) in a way which should do what you want for HTTP, and it also looks like you can [extend Wireshark](http://wiki.wireshark.org/Development) which will allow you to view other protocols.

Comment: Hi,I tried to extend fiddler using fiddlercore, but it constatly gives me an error, and even in fiddler mailing list, that question has been asked and no answer has been provided! :(
on the context of extending wireshark, firstly I don't know any ANSI C, secondly, it seems too heavy on performance, so that is not an option! but thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: @Upul - No problem, perhaps try to ask another question regarding Fiddler